# firebase issue with auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an issue with firebase auth, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: app.auth is not a function. (In 'app.auth()', 'app.auth' is
> undefined)

I write these lines of code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app' 
import "firebase/auth"

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})

export const auth = app.auth()
export default app
```

I tryed to replace with require the import of firebase/auth but it doesn't work, I tryed to uninstall and reinstall all node_modules but it didn't work, somebody can help me?

Comment: `firebase.auth()`?

Comment: don't work @Phix

Comment: Hey @GabrieleSabatino, did my answer work? If yes you can accept it by clicking (✅) icon so others will know issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the name-spaced syntax from V8 then use compat version of auth SDK as well:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app' 
import "firebase/compat/auth"
//                ^^^
```

I would recommend [upgrading to the new Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) for better performance and also the compat versions will be removed in upcoming updates.

```
import { initiliazeApp } from 'firebase/app' 
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const app = initializeApp({...config})

export const auth = getAuth(app)
export default app
```